# log4j dont write in file

Tags: java, cassandra, log4j

i work with ubuntu 16.04. i want to write log in file in program that have cassandra java api. the log be written in java console but dont be written in file.

my program :

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.*;
import com.datastax.driver.core.*;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class DbAdmin {

    private Cluster cluster;
    private Session session;
    private ResultSet R;
    private int Count = 1;
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DbAdmin.class.getName());

    public DbAdmin() throws IOException {
        try {
            this.cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(address).withCredentials(authecation).build();
            this.session = cluster.connectkeyspace);
            logger.debug("Connect to database");
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
```

and my log4j.properties :

```
    # Define the root logger with appender file
log = /home/sah/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/g.log

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your slf4j.properties to log4j.properties as Log4j by default searches for a file named **log4j.properties** in the classpath. If you want to use different name, you will need to configure property file explicitly by using org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.

Comment: sorry it was log4j.properties.i edit question @abhisrivastava24

Comment: Your log4j configuration seems fine. Check permissions on your log folder ${log}. Whether your program can write to a file in the log folder or not.

Comment: the other simple program can write in same file @abhisrivastava24

Answer (score 0):

If log4j can not found log4j.properties, it will use the default log4j.properties which only has console appender. So the console output not means you correctly log4j.properties.

The content of the log4j.properties you provide is correct.
So you need to check log4j.properties is in the classpath and has permission to write log to the file.

You also explicitly configure log4j.properties by code.
PropertyConfigurator.configure(....)

Comment: it is the path of log4j.properties https://ibb.co/gtxvva. and how can i check premision? @begginghard

Comment: ls -al /home/sah/log4j

you use IDEA to run application ? else run a package jar ?

Comment: i use intellij and maven and cassandra  @begginghard

Comment: I am sorry I can't help you.  do you have email, send me more information?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045361/log4j-2-not-writing-into-file/42061195#42061195